# Does NetBeans 8.2 do not support overlaying buttons on top of each other?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

The reason why I want them to be overlaid is because I will just use `.setVisible()` to which button I want to appear in the UI. But when I try to put them on top of each other, they push everything aside. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

EDIT: they push other components in Design Mode but if I put them side by side, it works. However, the other components is disarranged. Also, the actual UI is not similar to what is displayed in Design Mode (which is annoying).

Comment: You probably need to use a different layout manager.

Comment: This has little to do with the IDE and everything to do with layouts & Java. Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for the tip. I simply redesign my UI for now. But for my future projects, I will look to this layouts more.

Comment: *Also, the actual UI is not similar to what is displayed in Design Mode (which is annoying).* - don't use the IDE to create the form. The IDE is in control of the layout, not you. Learn to write the code to control the layout and the code will be easier to maintain and it will be portable if you ever move to another IDE. Only use the IDE to organize your classes and debug etc.